# Fluentd corrupted messages

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, fluentd, fluent-docker

I have a strange problem. I am sending the logs of my kubernetes cluster to Kafka using Fluentd. Everything works fine when I tell Fluentd to send the messages to a single topic partition. But when I tell Fluentd to distribute the messages in the different partitions that topic has, then it throws errors indicating that the messages are corrupted.

I've done a lot of reading and I'm pretty sure it's a problem in my kafka cluster and not in Fluentd. But I really don't know, the strongest theory I have is that there is a problem with the offset, sadly I don't know much about kafka.

Any idea what is happening?

This is my kafka configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-hs
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: server
    protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kafka
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  replicas: 3
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: bitmaker-kafka
      containers:
      - name: k8skafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: fastop/kafka:2.2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: server
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} \
          --override listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 \
          --override zookeeper.connect=zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 \
          --override log.dir=/var/lib/kafka \
          --override auto.create.topics.enable=true \
          --override auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true \
          --override background.threads=10 \
          --override compression.type=producer \
          --override delete.topic.enable=false \
          --override leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300 \
          --override leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10 \
          --override log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000 \
          --override log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.retention.bytes=-1 \
          --override log.retention.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.jitter.hours=0 \
          --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 \
          --override log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000 \
          --override message.max.bytes=1000012 \
          --override min.insync.replicas=1 \
          --override num.io.threads=8 \
          --override num.network.threads=3 \
          --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 \
          --override num.replica.fetchers=1 \
          --override offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096 \
          --override offsets.commit.required.acks=-1 \
          --override offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000 \
          --override offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880 \
          --override offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 \
          --override offsets.retention.minutes=1440 \
          --override offsets.topic.compression.codec=0 \
          --override offsets.topic.num.partitions=50 \
          --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 \
          --override offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600 \
          --override queued.max.requests=500 \
          --override quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override replica.fetch.min.bytes=1 \
          --override replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500 \
          --override replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000 \
          --override replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000 \
          --override replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536 \
          --override replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override request.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 \
          --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override unclean.leader.election.enable=true \
          --override zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override zookeeper.set.acl=false \
          --override broker.id.generation.enable=true \
          --override connections.max.idle.ms=600000 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.enable=true \
          --override controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000 \
          --override controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override default.replication.factor=1 \
          --override fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=300000 \
          --override group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override inter.broker.protocol.version=2.2.0 \
          --override log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000 \
          --override log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728 \
          --override log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 \
          --override log.cleaner.enable=true \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0 \
          --override log.cleaner.threads=1 \
          --override log.cleanup.policy=delete \
          --override log.index.interval.bytes=4096 \
          --override log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime \
          --override log.preallocate=false \
          --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 \
          --override max.connections.per.ip=2147483647 \
          --override num.partitions=5 \
          --override producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576 \
          --override replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=1000 "
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value : "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
        - name: KAFKA_OPTS
          value: "-Dlogging.level=INFO"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

My zookeeper configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-hs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2888
    name: follower
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 3888
    name: leader
    protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-cs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: client
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: zk-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zk
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  serviceName: zk-hs
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zk
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: bitmaker-kafka
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: fastop/zookeeper:3.4.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: follower
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "start-zookeeper \
          --servers=3 \
          --data_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
          --data_log_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data/log \
          --conf_dir=/opt/zookeeper/conf \
          --client_port=2181 \
          --election_port=3888 \
          --server_port=2888 \
          --tick_time=2000 \
          --init_limit=10 \
          --sync_limit=5 \
          --heap=512M \
          --max_client_cnxns=60 \
          --snap_retain_count=3 \
          --purge_interval=12 \
          --max_session_timeout=40000 \
          --min_session_timeout=4000 \
          --log_level=INFO"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

And this is my my fluentd configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentdconf
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <source>
        @type tail
        @id in_tail_container_logs
        path "/var/log/containers/*.log"
        pos_file "/var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos"
        tag "kubernetes.*"
        exclude_path []
        read_from_head true
        <parse>
            @type "/^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/"
            time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
            unmatched_lines 
            expression ^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$
            ignorecase false
            multiline false
        </parse>
    </source>

    <match fluent.**>
        @type null
    </match>

    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type kubernetes_metadata
      skip_container_metadata true
      skip_master_url true
      skip_namespace_metadata true
      skip_labels true
    </filter>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**fluentd**.log>
      @type null
    </match>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**kube-system**.log>
      @type null
    </match>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**jobcontainer**.log>
      @type kafka2
      @id out_kafka2
      brokers kafka-0.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-1.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-2.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
      default_topic "testlogs"
      get_kafka_client_log true
      max_send_retries 1
      required_acks -1
      max_send_limit_bytes 100000000
      compression_codec "gzip"
      ack_timeout
      discard_kafka_delivery_failed false
      share_producer true
      <format>
          @type "json"
      </format>
    </match>
```

En this is my daemonset for fluentd:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.11-debian-kafka2-1
        env:
        - name:  FLUENT_KAFKA_BROKERS
          value: "kafka-1.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"
        - name:  FLUENT_KAFKA_DEFAULT_TOPIC
          value: "testlogs"
        - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
          value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/
        - name: FLUENT_KAFKA_COMPRESSION_CODEC
          value: "gzip"
        - name: FLUENT_KAFKA_MAX_SEND_LIMIT_BYTES
          value: "1000000"
        - name: FLUENT_KAFKA_REQUIRED_ACKS
          value: "1"
        - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
          value: "bitmaker-workers"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: fluentconfig
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc/
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: fluentconfig
        configMap:
          name: fluentdconf
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Comment: Please show your configs as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Okey, the solution was this:
The topic to which I was sending the messages had been initially created with 1 single partition. But after it was modified to have multiple partitions, something that I can somehow corrupt the topic to receive messages on multiple partitions at once. What I did was create a new partitioned topic and everything works perfectly fine.